# IOS Core location - Find out nearest branch

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I have create a program to find out my current location using IOS corelocation framework.It works fine.

I need to create a program that list nearest branchaes of a shop chain, while a user travel with the phone.My data base contains the branches details with Latitude and lognitude.How i compare with these details to find out the nearest branch.

Help is highly appreciated.Anybody knows any example program

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `distanceFromLocation:` method of [CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocation).

> **distanceFromLocation:**
>
> Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the
>   specified location.
>
> - (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation
>     *)location
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ```
> location
>
> The other location.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The distance (in meters) between the two locations.
>   **Discussion**
>
> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

By using this method to get the distances of the shops with your current location, you can then sort the list based on the distance to get the nearest branch

Answer (score 0):

VKS, I got to solve the exact same problem too now (using apptarget iOS 5). Do you have any example code / snippets / tips to share for this problem, that I assumed you solved a long time ago? The above is very good explanation from 7KV7, but some examples will speed up my process a lot. Thank's :-)